# Tomcat 8 says it started but is not running on Linux / CentOS

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, tomcat8

New to Tomcat.  Downloaded and unpacked tomcat 8.0.9 to my CentOS web server.  Placed files in /opt/tomcat.

/opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh contains:

JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
CATALINA_PID="$CATALINA_BASE/tomcat.pid"

My environment variable for CATALINA_HOME is set to /opt/tomcat, double checked by using:

set | grep CATALINA_HOME

> CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat

Running /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh outputs:

/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/tomcat/tomcat.pid
>   Existing PID file found during start.
>   Removing/clearing stale PID file.
>   Tomcat started.

However, it doesn't really start.  When I check netstat there is nothing listening on 8080:

netstat -tulpn

> Active Internet connections (only servers)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1303/sshd
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1065/master
>   tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      1504/httpd
>   tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1303/sshd
>   tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1065/master
>   tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      1504/httpd

and no process named tomcat

ps aux | grep "tomcat"

> root     15193  0.0  0.0 103244   852 pts/0    S+   08:40   0:00 grep tomcat

Finally, when I run the shutdown.sh script it confirms that there was no tomcat process running even though the .pid file was created.

/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Using CATALINA_PID:    /opt/tomcat/tomcat.pid
>   PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

JRE_HOME variable was incorrect.  It was pointed to the actual java binary rather than the java folder.

> JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

was replaced with:

> JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64

in the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh file.

Discovered the problem after looking at the $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out file and seeing error messaging that the JRE_HOME variable was not a valid folder.